# How to make a parent element collection with a child collection

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm not all that familiar with markup. I tried to use it to test a `DataTemplate` with `TreeView`. Basically I'm trying to make a list named `parents`, add 2 elements to it, and then create two children and add them to one of the parents in the list, finally to bind the parent list to the `TreeView`. But I can't figure out how to reference `p1, p2` inside list. Now I think I shouldn't have wasted my time with xaml and should have done this in code behind. Any ideas?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Parent Name="Parent 1" x:Key="p1"/>
    <local:Parent Name="Parent 2" x:Key="p2"/>
    <x:ArrayExtension Type="local:Parent" x:Key="parents">
        <!-- Can't refer p1 and p2 from here :( -->        
    </x:ArrayExtension>

    <local:Child ChildName="Child 1" Parent="{StaticResource ResourceKey=p1}"/>
    <local:Child ChildName="Child 1" Parent="{StaticResource ResourceKey=p1}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=p1}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The two classes :

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    private Parent _parent;
    public Parent Parent 
    {
        get
        {
            return _parent;
        }
        set
        {
            _parent = value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                value.Children.Add(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No need to place `TreeView` in a `StackPanel`. `StackPanel` stacks elements, but in your case there's only one element in it - the `TreeView`.
2. You need to define `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the `TreeView`. Here's an example:

---

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
    <!--  Some markup here -->
</ HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Here `ItemsSource` property tells what property in bound data containes collection of children of current node. It is applied recursively to every child and every child of that child and so on.

---

At last, about defining data in xaml. There are several approaches, but in this situation I would rather derive from `Parent` with `ParentTest` and create default c'tor that fills Children collection.